# Derivative of a complex vector help.

Tags: linear-algebra

In a paper I am reading, the author defines a derivative of a L2 norm giving a solution as follows:

$$\delta\{\|Dx - y\|^2\} + \lambda\|(G-I)x\|^2 = 2D^{*}(Dx-y) + \lambda 2(G-I)^*(G-I)x$$

The * is the hermitian operator and vectors are complex vectors.
I don't understand how the author did the derivation and went from left side to the right side. Any help in showing the derivation will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The [first variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation) should be applied to the entire expression on the LHS to get the RHS.

Comment: You shouldn't alternate in and out of MathJax multiple times within one line.  I've edited it so that the whole line is a single instance of MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

The [derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition) of the squared norm functional is a linear map (wrt $h$ below) that can be found as follows
$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{0}\|D(x+th)-y\|^{2}
\\
=
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{0}\langle D(x+th)-y,D(x+th)-y\rangle
\\
= \Re(2\left\langle Dx-y,Dh\right\rangle)\\
= \Re(2{\left\langle D^{*}(Dx-y),h\right\rangle}) . $$
The gradient vector is then $\Re(2D^{*}(Dx-y))$. The derivative of the second term is found similarly.